# Installed 16.04 but cannot get machine to direct boot to Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I'm trying to install 16.04 on a Lenovo p710 and cannot get the machine to boot to anything other than windows. If I boot to windows and then restart while holding shift, I am able to select Ubuntu and get in that way, but obviously that is less than ideal. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated to this Linux novice!

Here is the link to the file created by boot repair:  https://paste2.org/UBXWXHF4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First boot into ubuntu in the way you are able to then:

Open up the terminal by pressing `CTRL + ALT + T`,

now type in `sudo apt get install grub*`.

After the installation try rebooting your system and see if this makes any difference.